# How can i change color of action bar and its over flow menu?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

Here is a screenshot of my application:
[image]

I can access buttons using R.id.button1 and change its background using

```
case R.id.lightgreen:
          for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
                currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lightgreen);
            }
```

Is there any way to access action bar and its overflow menu to set their color in same way?

**[EDIT]**

```
ActionBar actnbar;
actnbar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.blue_button);
```

this gives me error asking to convert blue_button to drawable but if i do that then i won't be able to set buttons.

Comment: you can change `ActionBar` background using `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable()`...

Comment: is there something else i need to write because just writing
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable()
gives error.

Comment: `actionBar.setBackgroundColor(new ColorDrawable(required_color));`...

Comment: I am editing my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Define your custom style.xml in values folder of your project like this :

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.CustomTHeme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.CustomTHeme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.CustomTHeme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/header_gradient</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.CustomTHeme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.CustomTHeme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And then in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomTHeme">
...
```

You also must take care of supporting other api-s (other values folders).

If you are using actionbarcompat support library you can access actionbar in your activity that extends `ActionBarActivity` with `getSupportActionBar()` and use 
`setStackedBackgroundDrawable()` or `setBackgroundDrawable()` or corresponding getActionBar() method if not using support library.

Comment: This is what i was using initially but then i am unable to set custom background for buttons.

Comment: What error do you get if you get one? How do you mean buttons, they are not in actionbar like menu or something? Can you debug your code to that line to see what happens?

Comment: Initially i was using action bar style generator, it generated a theme like you said above, then whenever i tried to change style of buttons using "@style/Widget.AppCompat.Buttons" i was getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

The [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/%E2%80%8E) is a great tool to style your action bar.

Comment: If i create a theme using action bar style generator, then i don't know how will i stylise my buttons i.e., 1,2,3 etc. in my application.